# CSS header tag question

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to place normal size text on the same line as a header tag. Doing this put the normal size text on the next line because a header tag is a block element.

```
<h1>Header</h1>normal size text
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
h1{display:inline;}
```

Will cause the H1 Tag to stop blocking

Comment: But it doesn't work on IE6, moves it to the next line, any tips? I know IE6 must die but until it does, I need to fix it.

Comment: `h1{display:inline;}` and `<h1>Hello There</h1>You Crazy World`  Worked fine for me on IE6.. are there any other styles being applied?  If you are unsure you can try `h1{display:inline !important;}`

Comment: You are right, your code works in IE6 but there are a bunch more other styles in play, I need to sort out the offending one, thanks.

Comment: @Bob, you may want to use a CSS-reset stylesheet to remove the browser defaults and style the elements you need. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/116754/best-css-reset for a discussion of some of the available options.

Answer (score 0):

Or, if you don't want to use inline elements, float the h1 instead:

```
h1 {
    float:left;
}
```

In some scenarios *may* need to wrap both the h1 and normal size text in a div, that's also floated left, to keep it contained on the same line:

```
<div id="foo"><h1>Hello</h1>World</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

alternatively, you might want to try

```
<h1>Header <span class="normal">normal size text</span></h1>
```

, and style the .normal span using css to look like normal text.  not semantic, but visually works even in IE6.